# Multiple startup projects solution deployment automatization with Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

This is the setup.
I have a VS2013 solution with 40-50 projects and I need 4 of them deployed to server. I am using Jenkins to do the thing. The msbuild plugin is great for that.
I add 4 sections with msbuild in the Jenkins job configuration.
[This is a picture of an example msbuild section from the configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGWln.png)

When I run the build gives error at 3 places no matter what msbuild section it is currently on, but all errors are on the same class library. Edit:[ On recent builds I got one more Class Library with similar error.] I have no problem when I am building everything locally via VS2013. But building 4 configurations and replacing dlls with obfuscated dlls takes time and I want to reduce it with Jenkins:)

The errors are:

1. error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
2. error MSB3023: No destination specified for Copy. Please supply either "DestinationFiles" or "DestinationFolder".
3. The "FindUnderPath" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Path".

I saw some other posts about the first error and tried using the answers but it didn't help. (Deleting Platform envoiremental variable or modifying the .csproj in txt editor, or reseting the output in vs)

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days looking for answer and deciding to post here I kinda fixed it:D
I added /p:OutputPath="C:\test" in the parameters of msbuild so it applies everything there.
If i go /bin/Debug or /bin/Release I get that problem where file name is too big.
so i decided to put everything in C:/test